# What is monotonous and non-monotonous flow?

Tags: aerodynamics, fluid-mechanics

I'm not an engineering graduate so I'm learning as I go along. I've just read a sentence that states:

> The transition shapes are identical, while the variety of growth rates of intermittency
> are non-monotonous with the increase in aerodisk length

My exhaustive google search does not show any results that in a basic form explain what is "non-monotonous" as well as how its related to intermittency

Can someone please explain what this is?

I read this from here: https://www.mdpi.com/2226-4310/9/12/742

Comment: Hi! I think a bit more background could get you a better answer. For starters, where did you read this?

Comment: Updated description showing reading material with the above quote

Comment: I suppose they meant [monotonic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing.
In this paper, wherever the adjective monotonous appears, it modifies growth rate, not flow.

Also, the word should be monotonic, not monotonous.
Although MDPI is no longer regarded as a predatory journal, it is still [not respected](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/5466/52541).  A gaffe like this shows that its reviewers are shoddy.

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful. A sad waste of time on my behalf, weeks of breaking down learnings wasted on such a journal :(